# Check the value from DBand pass it to next page

Tags: php

I have a field ,if user enters data it should go and check db if it is present it should redirect to next page.

But here i m not sure whether it is checking the db but mysql query is correct.

```
$ThirdPartyCategoryName =$_POST['ThirdPartyCategoryName'];

$activate = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `thirdpartycategorymaster` WHERE `delete` =  'y' ");

if($activate=='y')
{
    header("location:catact.php");
}
else
{
    //$activate=='NULL';
    header("location:tp_home.php");
}
```

Comment: check `print_r($activate)` and see what is in it.

Comment: Your Question is not clear. `$ThirdPartyCategoryName` is not being used anywhere

Comment: It is the name of the text box from which value is posted here.

Comment: @NAVEED: I get this Resource id #4

Comment: @user I think you would benefit a lot more from reading a book or two about PHP and MySQL than asking lots of questions here. I hope you don't mind my saying so, but it seems you're still in way over your head with not a very firm grasp on the basics.

Comment: @user554176: So `$activate` cant be equal to `'y'`. You should convert it to array form and then check `'delete'` column value from that array. Look at **HoLyVieR's** answer below.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_query` returns a ressource that you need to parse with function such as `mysel_fetch_array`. Your first condition will always be false, you have to parse the ressource before comparing the result contained in it.

```
$ressource = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `thirdpartycategorymaster` WHERE `delete` =  'y'");
$firstLine = mysql_fetch_array($ressource);

if ($firstLine && $firstLine['delete'] == 'y') {
     // There is an entry with delete = y
} else {
    // There is no entry with delete = y
}
```

This code could also be simplify to just this :

```
$ressource = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `thirdpartycategorymaster` WHERE `delete` =  'y'");

if (mysql_fetch_array($ressource)) {
     // There is an entry with delete = y
} else {
    // There is no entry with delete = y
}
```

Or also :

```
$ressource = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `thirdpartycategorymaster` WHERE `delete` =  'y'");

if (mysql_num_rows($ressource) > 0) {
     // There is an entry with delete = y
} else {
    // There is no entry with delete = y
}
```

Comment: +1 That query and following logic is still pretty screwed though. :)

Comment: @user There was a little typo in the answer, I've corrected it.

Comment: Here if it is not y also it is redirecting to first header only.

Comment: @user This query only selects **all entries** from the database where the `delete` field equals `y`, and the condition only checks whether there are any such records or not. First of all, there are more efficient ways to do this, but most of all, this doesn't seem like it has anything to do with what you're trying to do. You'll need to rethink your logic of what you're actually doing here.

Comment: @user Are you sure you are not missing some condition in your SQL query ? Is the POST parameter "ThirdPartyCategoryName" suppose to do anything in the query ?

Comment: @HoLyVieR, deceze: I have posted clearly what i want my query to do.I want to select if that category name is y,if so it has to go to other page where it will be udated to NULL or else it has to go to main page.Hope am i clear now.